# AVI to iPhone Converter for Linux OS?

Tags: linux, video, iphone, conversion

Is there any free GOOD video converter for Linux, which can also convert from AVI to iPhone?
I need something with good quality.

Using Linux Mint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a really good video converter. It's free, open-source and cross-platform:

> There's an old proverb in the video
>   encoding world: "Speed, size, quality:
>   pick two." It means that you always
>   have to make a trade-off between the
>   time it takes to encode a video, the
>   amount of compression used, and the
>   picture quality. Well, this release of
>   HandBrake refuses to compromise. It
>   picks all three.

Answer (score 4):

By iPhone, I assume you mean mpeg4. There's a lot of command line tools that can achieve that. The main ones are [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) and [mplayer/mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

You can also have a look at [this Nautilus script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=193754&highlight=avi+dvd+script).

Comment: i'd suggest in addition taking a look at winff as a ffmpeg front end.

Answer (score 1):

Try ***Avidemux*** : it have a GTK+ gui is complete and more user-friendly in comparison to other command line editors, you can find it in the repository.